# Relocating MySQL data files

Tags: opensuse, mysql5

I would like to move everything that is related to my current MySQL database(s) into a subdirectory of `/home/mysql`. I don't need to move log files or `my.cnf`, only **data**.

I don't know where the actual database files are stored and how to tell MySQL to load them from a different directory after I move them.

Can you give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data directory is specified by the datadir variable. You can check to see what the current data directory is with a:

```
show variables like 'datadir';
```

In your my.cnf under the [mysqld] section you can set:

```
datadir=/path/to/mysql/data
```

Cheers